Roundtrip deserialization breaks SObject equality with Decimals
JSON roundtrip breaks equality contract when the SObject contains Decimal fields.
Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity(Amount = 12.3);
Opportunity o2 = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(o1), Opportunity.class);
System.debug(o1 == o2); // false

Is there a way to prevent this?
Opportunity o3 = new Opportunity(Name = 'foo');
Opportunity o4 = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(o3), Opportunity.class);
System.debug(o3 == o4); // true


Some additional system.debug() makes this look like an issue with SObject comparison rather than an issue with the Decimal type (or at least not with the Decimal type alone). System.debug(o1.Amount == o2.Amount); returns true. The hashCode for o1 is different from that of o2. Maybe there's a disconnect somewhere and something is getting converted to a Double or a Float and then back to Decimal?

When debugging, roundtrip "1.0" is converted to "1", while a non-roundtripped "1.0" stays as "1.0".

May I know what do you mean by roundtrip "1.0" is converted to "1"? Because like @Derek F, said, I printing o1 and o2 Amount value gives the same value of "12.3".

It's the other way around.
Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity(Amount = 1);
Opportunity o2 = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(o1), Opportunity.class);
System.debug(o1); // Opportunity:{Amount=1}
System.debug(o2); // Opportunity:{Amount=1.0}

Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity(Amount = 12.3);
Opportunity o2 = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(o1), Opportunity.class);
System.debug(o1 == o2); // false

However, if we System.debug(o1.Amount) and System.debug(o2.Amount). I get the same value 12.3. But when checked with == operator they are still false.
To answer your question, to resolve this to true. You can cast the field back to it's original data type. For example;
Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity(Amount = 12.3);
System.debug(o1.Amount); //12.3
Opportunity o2 = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(o1), Opportunity.class);
System.debug(o2.Amount);//12.3
System.debug(o1 == o2); // false

o2.Amount = (Decimal) o2.Amount;
System.debug(o1 == o2); // true


I'm not looking to compare field values, I'm looking for SObject comparison, which is broken by the deserialization roundtrip.

@ipavlic I had a tough time seeing what was happening here based on prem22's description, but in the end... doing the decimal re-casting does restore the object equality that you are looking for. o1 and o2 are still Opportunities.
